# удаление картинок из директории

Tags: php

Подскажите, что за... Не получается удалить картинки товаров из папки при удалении записей из базы данных.
Подключаю БД,  далее вот такой код:

```
// получаем имя картинки
$result = "SELECT pimage FROM products WHERE id =" . $_REQUEST['id'];
try {
    $query = $db->query($result);
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $query->fetch();
    $img = $row[pimages];
    $dir='../../images/products/';       
    // удаляем файл
    unlink($dir.$img);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   die($e->getMessage());
}
// Delete product image
$sqlimg = "DELETE FROM productimages WHERE id = " . $_REQUEST['id'];
try {
    $query = $db->prepare($sqlimg);
    $query->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Вторая часть кода `// Delete product image` и далее - работают нормально, а первая никак.
Права на файлы 755 и 664 Директория от обработчика 2 папки назад. Что здесь не так? помогите.

Comment: Мда... Когда же вы начнёте пользоваться подготовленными запросами?! Замените `unlink($dir.$img);` на `var_dump(unlink($dir.$img));` и скажите что пишет

Comment: интересно, зачем таблица productimages  если имя картинки лежит в products

Comment: @ArchDemon -  заменил на  var_dump(unlink($dir.$img)); пишет такое: bool(false)

Comment: Добавил после var_dump(unlink($dir.$img)); для показа ошибки  echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";  - ничего кроме bool(false) не выводит?

Comment: Подключил вывод ошибок и вот что вижу:  Warning: unlink(../../images/products/): Is a directory in /home/q/q95193s0/private.sewing/public_html/cyfrachop/cp/functions/delete_image.php on line 29   Что за ерунда написана? Как это она находится по этому адресу?

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом все заработало:

```
// получаем имя картинки
$result = "SELECT pimage FROM productimages WHERE id= " . $_REQUEST['id'];
try{
    $query = $db->query($result);
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $query->fetch();       
    // удаляем файл
    unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cyfrachop/images/products/'.$row['pimage']);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй

```
$result = "SELECT pimage FROM products WHERE id ='{$_REQUEST['id']}'";
```

Comment: @YouMixx-  К сожалению и не это. Даже по прямому id не удаляет.